# On a possible probabilistic log-rank conjecture

Tags: pr.probability, communication-complexity

The communication matrix of a function $f$ is a $2^{n}\times 2^{n}$ matrix $M_f$ where the indices of the rows (columns) correspond to the inputs of Alice (Bob), and each entry $M_f (a,b)$ is the function value $f(a,b)$.

The log-rank conjecture asserts that for the communication complexity $CC(f)$ it holds that $ CC(f) = (\log rank (M_{f}))^{O(1)}$.

Given $k\in\Bbb N$, is it known whether 
$$\mathsf{P}(CC(f) \leq (\log r)^{k})\geq1-\frac{1}{p(k)}$$ 
where the probability is over $0/1$ matrices $M_f$ of fixed rank $rank (M_{f})=r$, for a polynomial $p(x)\in\Bbb Z_{\geq0}[x]$ or 
$$\mathsf{P}(CC(f) \leq (\log r)^{k})\geq1-\frac{1}{n^k}$$ 
where the probability is over $2^n\times 2^n$ $0/1$-matrices $M_f$ of fixed rank $rank (M_{f})=r$ ?

Comment: By 'probability over $rank(M_f)$ matrices', do you mean you are randomly choosing different $f$ (and therefore $M_f$) of some constant rank, or if $f$ is fixed what is the random choice?

Comment: different $M_f$.

Comment: I still don't understand what is being chosen at random. Can you be more precise? Do you randomly choose a Boolean matrix from the set of all Boolean matrices? Or randomly choose a Boolean matrix from the set of all Boolean matrices that have fixed rank r? Or something else?

Comment: We choose $M_f$ uniformly from fixed rank $r$ matrices.